# how to create a guest account without disk encryption password prompted

Tags: password, encryption, accounts, useradd

I'd like to let people use my computer sometime without entering into my session

that's usually achieve with guest account, for example using `sudo useradd guest` and `sudo passwd -d guest`

but my computer disk is encrypted, so it ask for a sda5_crypt password at start, before the user account choice

can i create a guest account that wouldn't ask for the encryption password ? Actually i think no, i will look for a dual boot instead, but i wanted to be sure and ask here

Comment: Your startup disk cannot be both encrypted (for you) and decrypted (for guests) simultaneously. You gotta pick one state for everybody. You can boot from an unencrypted disk, or let your guests use the "Try Ubuntu" environment of the installer. That has it's own risks, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your current configuration, this will require one of these :

- Giving your guests your passphrase to allow them to log as guest once the system booted.
- Create additional passphrase you will revoke when the guests are left.
- Create an additional system image with preconfigured software, guest user without privileges on another disk (or partition if the whole disk is not encrypted).
- Create a bootable live system with preconfigured software and unprivileged account to boot from (i)PXE and run from memory.

Comment: so i still have to figure out the exact meaning of the two last options, but what i understand is that there are no configuration (except if i give them the passphrase) in wich my guests could have root privileges on their session ? Which means they couldn't use sudo or install new softwares ?

Comment: Unlocking encrypted volume and sudo privileges are two separate things, initial question was about encryption only.